# Eclipse cannot find library

Tags: eclipse, cordova, reference

I'm stuck in this tutorial: http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.ie/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html

In the part: Prepare the Activity-Class

Because my Eclipse cannot find the class DroidGap.

It seems to be there some problem referencing a library in Eclipse, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to follow a very old tutorial (phonegap 2.2) and maybe trying with a recent version.

I would suggest you cancel this tutorial and try to follow cordova's documantations :

- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface
- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Thanks but the thing is that I'm using windows and on cms the command cordova doesn't exist....

Comment: Also could I try the tutorial with phoegap2.2.0? since this tutorial is graphical and much more intuitive

Comment: Folllowing your tutorial got stock in the command cordova platform add android Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.

Comment: ant is part of the requirements listed in the second link I provided. You need to download apache ant and add its bin folder to the path. About your tutorial, if you find somewhere a version of phonegap 2.2, yes you can follow it but in my opinion you will loose your time as things change quite much since then.